# Help me! Не добавляются данные в mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Не могу найти ошибку. Пишет: данные не добавлены.

```html
<?php
    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $pass=""; //установленный вами пароль
    $db_name="mydatesite";
    $link=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    mysql_select_db($db_name,$link);
?>

<?php
$puls = $_POST['puls'];
$davl = $_POST['davl'];

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'dateofuser' (puls, davl) VALUES ('$puls', '$davl')");

//Если запрос пройдет успешно то в переменную result вернется true

if($result == 'true')

{echo "Ваши данные успешно добавлены";}

else {echo "Ваши данные не добавлены";}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<title>Админ-панель</title>
</head>
<body>

<table>

<form name="forma" action="form.php" method="post">

<br><input name="puls" type="text"><br>

 <br><input name="davl" type="text"><br>

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Добавить запись">

</form>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Так вызовите функцию `mysqli_error` и посмотрите что за ошибка, в чем проблема? У MySQL достаточно подробные и понятные сообщения.

Comment: Ежели **Help ME!** то это скорее [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
if($result == 'true')
```

это уже неправильный код, потому что в этой интерпретации 'true' - это строка, и никак не boolean

два следующих варианта возможны:

```
if($result == true)
```

или

```
if($result)
```

или еще лучше :

```
if (mysql_error() == '')
```

и в случае неуспеха, распечатать значение mysql_error(), чтобы понять в чем состоит ошибка

Хочется отметить, что модуль MySQL уже устарел и следует использовать или MySQLi или PDO, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Answer (score 0):

Скобки лишние в запросе, исправил Ваш запрос:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `dateofuser` (`puls`, `davl`) VALUES ('$puls', '$davl')");
```

Нужно использовать либо тильду (`), либо ничего.

Так же рекомендую перейти на [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php), а лучше на [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php), mysql устарел.